# Complete list of Somei Satohs works

Tags: japan, discography

I'm looking for a complete list of Somei Satohs works. The list on the english Wiki is rather incomplete as it misses for example

- The Heavenly Spheres Are Illuminated By Lights
- Birds In Warped Time II
- A Gate Into The Stars
- Litania

and more. Petrucci doesn't even list Satoh.

Can someone help?

Comment: The english wiki has links elsewhere, which give more comprehensive links,  [Satoh's own website](http://someis.wix.com/home#!portfolio) for example.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you know a Wikipedia article is incomplete, you can always edit it yourself.  It might be a service to other Satohs fans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go with [Satoh's own website](http://someis.wix.com/home). (note: requires Adobe Flash to view)  All the works you mention are listed under the discography.

Likewise, further information can be had from the various record labels :
[New Albion Records](http://www.newalbion.com/apps/search?q=satoh), [ALM records](http://www.kojimarokuon.com/index.html). Other record labels such as [Omega point](http://omega-point.shop-pro.jp/?mode=cate&cbid=1339679&csid=0&sort=n) and [Fontec](http://www.fontec.co.jp/english/english.html) just list works, with little other information.

Comment: Also Disgogs may list all releases.

Comment: Thanks @Bebs - here is [https://www.discogs.com/search/?q=Somei+Satoh&type=all](link to Discogs search for Somei Satoh). I am not familiar with Discogs myself, but it seems an easier way to find releases on defunct labels - at least one of the labels mentioned above is under other ownership.